# how to change combobox values on keypress using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is not working

```
if($(".foo").is(':focus')){

   // do something

}
```

To change values on keypress:

```
$(".foo").bind("keypress", function(e){

   $(this).attr('value', 'bar'); 

})
```

Comment: attr('value', 'bar') ? maybe you wanted .val('bar') ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `val()` jquery function. Also you can directly use the `keypress()` function in this scenario.

```
$(".foo").keypress(function(e){

   $(this).val('bar'); 

});
```

**Note**: this will work given the fact that '.foo' will select the combobox itself and that 'bar' is the value of at least one of the options within it.